# Render custom HTML markup inside pdf document using react-pdf/render library

Tags: reactjs, pdf, html-to-pdf, react-pdf

I am trying to render HTML inside the `<View>/<Text>` component while rendering the PDF inside the  `<PDFViewer>` using a Template.

I'd like to render my custom HTML Markup code shown below in my pdf

`<p><span style="font-size: 24px;">Pre Interview Notes</span></p><p><br></p><p><strong style="font-size: 14px;"><u>This is a test Pre Interview Notes:</u></strong></p><p><br></p><p><em style="font-size: 14px;">The Guest requires a wheel chair for the show</em></p><p><br></p><p><br></p>`

**Environment**

- Browser  [e.g. Chrome ]:
- React-PDF version [1.6.8]:
- React version [e.g. 16.8.6]:

Comment: You will need to parse the HTML markup and re-create the output using the React-PDF components. I'm working on something similar now, except displaying Markdown instead of HTML. I've found the [unified](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unified) library useful for processing the input to a syntax tree. However, I'm having trouble getting inline font styles to work. If I make some more progress I might roll the entire process into a library.